# Download post from chatter in salesforce with Python

Tags: python, salesforce, simple-salesforce

I'm currently using simple-salesforce to retrieve data from various the object in salesforce, but I would also need to download the post in chatter of the associated object.

For instance, with an object `project_table__c` I need to get the associated post of each project.

| Project_id | Chatter post |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | test |
| 2 | hello |
| 2 | word |
| 2 | bird |

I might also be possible to get it with the rest API but I don't where I should go from here:

```py
from simple_salesforce import Salesforce 
import os 

username="username"
password=os.environ['SALESFORCE_PASSWORD']
security_token=os.environ['SALESFORCE_SECURITY_TOKEN']
domain="test"

sf = Salesforce(username=username,password=password, security_token=security_token,domain=domain)

report_results = sf.restful('chatter', method='GET')

print(report_results)
```

How could I achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general table to store Chatter posts is [FeedItem](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_feeditem.htm). You can query it directly but it'll have all chatter posts across all objects, you'd need to filter it with something like `select id, parentid from feeditem where parent.type = 'project_table__c ' limit 10`. Might get nasty quick and problematic if you need more fields from the parent object.

You probably have a "more specific" table `project_table__Feed` (similar to how you have autogenerated `project_table__History`, `project_table__Share`...). The reverse relationship name for this table will be `Feeds` so see how this works for you?

```
SELECT Id, Name,
    (SELECT Title, Body FROM Feeds)
FROM Project_Table__c
LIMIT 20
```

So try querying that with "simple" and see how it goes?

There's also whole [<strike>Chatter</strike> Connect REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.chatterapi.meta/chatterapi/features.htm)... More reading but hey, maybe simpler access?